# Typescript / Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

```
private nodes = [];

constructor(private nodeService: NodeService) {}    

    this.nodeService.getNodes('APIUrl')
            .subscribe((data) => {
            this.nodes.push(data);
        });


        console.log(this.nodes)
```

This is my component where I get the data.

```
getNodes(url) {
    return this.http.get(url)
    .map((data) => data.json())
}
```

This is my service where i get my data and map it

However when i console.log(this.nodes) in my component this is my result:

```
[1: Array[0]]
```

[And it is possible to see the structure of my data as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmlqm.png)

So my problem is when i console.log(this.nodes[0]) in my component, I get undefined. I can't seem to access my data as I need to. Any thoughts?

Comment: The code is asynchronous, look at the answer l linked to

Comment: Okey thanks will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Juan's comment, you need to move the console.log to be within the callback.

```
constructor(private nodeService: NodeService) {}    

    this.nodeService.getNodes('APIUrl')
            .subscribe((data) => {
            this.nodes.push(data);
            console.log(this.nodes)
        });
```

But really, your code indicates you don't understand the asynchronous nature of that service.  Do read and understand the answer he linked to.

Comment: I probably don't. I will take a step back to read up on things more. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yea how do you mean the code indicated i don'nt understand? Do you mean due to the fact that I am not utilizing the callback??